# How to store/send language specific characters via XML

Tags: php, xml, encoding, format

I have a system that uses AJAX to send/receive information from the server(PHP). On the server side, I am suppose to 'store' the following code to the XML and then read and use it on the client:

```
<div id="someDiv">Čiča Gliša</div>
```

The server itself gives no 'error' in the logs, the XML gets sent, but on the client side I get the "not well-formatted" error when attempting to read this.

The XML itself is 'created' with this line (as far as I can tell, I am not really a back-end dev, so I wouldn't be too proficient with these things, but it is the 'content' that is causing the issue this time so I am tasked with resolving it.

```
$this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml/>')
```

When I change the letters Č and Š to C and S it works. But I dont know how to make it work otherwise.

Using Mozzila on the client if it matters, freshly installed.

**EDIT: XML as requested in the comments**
(if i managed to debug it properly)
response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <client_contents>
    <frame>
        <![CDATA[
            <div id="upper">upper div</div><br>
            <div id="middle">middle</div><br>
            <div id="lower">lower div <br>
            <a onclick="ExecuteScenario('POST',6,1);">Run Something</a></div>
        ]]>
    </frame>
        <upper>
            <![CDATA[
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-7 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-offset-5  col-xs-offset-1 info-content">
                                    <div class="row title">
                        <h2>Naziv turisti?kog objekta</h2>
                    </div>
                                    <div class="one-info">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="data">
                            <p>Ulica Cica Gli�e 15</p>
                            <p>11215 Donji Svrd�ibrd�ilovci</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ]]>
        </upper>
        <middle>
            <![CDATA[
                <div> MENU </div>
            ]]>
        </middle>
    </client_contents>
<data_sets>
<Data>
</Data>
</data_sets>
<java_scripts/>
</xml>
```

What I did notice is that there is a closing  tag, without ever being an opening one, though this does not seem to be the cause of the error because as soon as I remove the characters `Č` the thing starts working.

Comment: you can just using cdata construction for example

Comment: Make use of php header content type utf 8 while reading or writing.

Comment: You mean in the HTML?

Comment: Might be the xml version problem. One common practice in western Europe is to use ISO-8859-1 so that the majority of common accented letters can be used as single bytes check http://xml.silmaril.ie/characters.html

Comment: But when creating the XML it is state that encoding should be UTF-8, I gave the line which creates the XML above. Is there a possibility that the browser is the culprit here and not the server? I believe there is nothign wrong with the XML, just that browser cannot interpret it?

Comment: Show us the source of the response that is sent to the browser. Use the developer tools in the browser to debug it. Are you sure that your characters are UTF-8 and that you do not output something before or after it?

Comment: I have two things that "appear to be the same" `response` and `responseText` they are, at least to my eye, the same, which one do you need?

Comment: @ThW added an edit, not sure if that is what you meant/requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue lies with the fact that the **string itself has to be converted before** it is sent INTO the XML. The string written in an editor, such as NetBeans has a certain kind of encoding (windows-1252) in this case, and if such a string is passed to the XML, regardless of the XML's encoding, it will be interpreted wrong.

Because [[CDATA]] would eat anything, it just keeps the string as is, then when the client receieves the data, it assumes the encoding is UTF-8 (because it says so in the XML), but in fact the string in there is not UTF-8, it is windows-1252 (which is what the developer enviroment uses).

**TL;DR**

```
iconv('windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $string); //current, wanted, string
```

Comment: The libxml APIs expect the provided values as UTF-8 and will return them as UTF-8. This is independent of the serialized XML string/file. I suggest storing your source files as UTF-8. (Netbeans should have an option for that.)

Answer (score -1):

you can just using cdata construction for example

`<mynode><![CDATA[Čiča Gliša]]></mynode>`

and correct encode for string, if this string `utf8` you need use `utf8` for you xml.

Comment: I am afraid I do not directly access adding of these nodes, mnerely the content that goes into them, but this is how they are added, from what I can figgure: `$DomNode->appendChild($n->createCDATASection($CC));` where $CC is the text that I wrote. I am assuming that `createCDATASection` gives the same result as your code above, in which case, it is not solving the issue. This is all in a loop that keeps creating new $DomNode elements as it goes through the content stack

Comment: @Dellirium You got error encode chars(non utf8 symbols)?

Comment: no, the error is as writtenL `Not well-formated` when attempting to access the XML node. This error is given by the browser's console, there is no error in the PHP logs.

Comment: @Dellirium if you create xml in php for ajax you can set `header('Content-type:application/xml')` and send response. You browser just can't detect format with out content-type or you content-type not valid for example `content-type:application/json` not xml this only json. p.s. sorry my English.

Comment: This code is present in the response method `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Dellirium you can show response header from server and xml?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand, you want me to show you how the method looks? The code?

Comment: @Dellirium You can user `json` format in your application. no problem I do not understand my self :D

Comment: Ah but I cannot use JSON, there are standards to uphold here, it is a big system, I cannot change things on a whim like that. It has to stay XML, but it also has to be able to send these characters, i dont know why it doesn't allow it since UTF-8 is set :S

Comment: @Dellirium I think you characters  Č is unicode symbol.

Comment: It is, and encoding is Unicode, so it should work, but it does not.